# Как менять прокси при каждом входе в цикл?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, считываю с сайта токен определённое кол-во раз. скажите, как при каждом входе в цикл брать новый прокси? все прокси хранятся в текстовом файле
вот что делаю:

```
static CookieDictionary cook = new CookieDictionary();
        String token = string.Empty;

        string GET(string url)//получение токена
        {
            var Proxy = File.ReadLines("proxy.txt").ToList();
            var count = Proxy.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < (int)numericUpDown1.Value; i++)
                    {
                foreach (var list in Proxy)
                        {

                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                        var request = new HttpRequest();
                        request.UserAgent = HttpHelper.ChromeUserAgent();

                           request.Proxy = HttpProxyClient.Parse(list);
                        request.Cookies = cook;

                        HttpResponse response = request.Get(url);
                        var z = response.ToString();
                        Match res = Regex.Match(z, "var AUTH_TOKEN = \"(.*)\";");
                        token = res.Groups[1].ToString();

                    }
                } 
            return token;    
        }
```

но в переменную list при запросе прогружаются сразу все прокси, как сделать так, чтоб при каждом входе в цикл брался следующий прокси?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> foreach (var list in Proxy)
> ```

```
var list = Proxy[i % Proxy.Count];
```

Comment: всё равно при каждом входе в цикл берёт сразу все прокси( есть другой способ?

Comment: К какой цикл? Эта строка вместо цикла.

Comment: я понял, что это вместо foreach. но цикл for же остался. при каждом входе в for в list сразу все ip прогружаются

Comment: Внимательнее...

Comment: попробуйте сами код запустить и посмотреть что в отладке будет)

Comment: Сам попробуй. Там нет ничего, почему бы оно не работало.

Comment: оно работает, но не совсем так как надо. если у меня будет в списке 10 ip например, то при каждом входе в list будут сразу все 10 штук загружаться и прогружаться при запросе, смекашеь?

Comment: Я написал, как это исправить.

Comment: var list = Proxy[i % Proxy.Count]; – используя такой способ будет всё то что я щас выше в комментах писал.

Comment: Каким образом? Есть массив, из него выбран один элемент. Цикла нет. Для каждой итерации for будет выбран 1 прокси, причём, если прокси достаточно, то для каждой свой.

Comment: каким каким, вот таким. был бы щас интернет быстрее, записал бы тебе видео отладки, как при каждой итерации в list прогружается каждый ip по очереди

Comment: "как при каждой итерации в list прогружается каждый ip по очереди" - так ты же это и просил?

Comment: в моей теме сразу под кодом написано "как сделать так, чтоб при каждом входе в цикл брался следующий прокси?", имеется в виду - вошёл в первый раз в цикл, взял первый прокси, второй раз зашёл, взял второй и т.д. 1 вход = 1 прокси, а не 1 вход = все прокси

Comment: Я не понимаю твой вопрос. В моём вариант 1 вход в цикл for = 1 http-запрос с 1 прокси. Если тебе надо не это, то объясни по-человечески.